# NIST's Recommendations for Protection of CLASSIFIED Data?

Tags: hash, aes, public-key, symmetric

In NIST [Recommendation for Key Management Part 1 Rev 4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf), It states in Section 1.Intro

> This NIST Recommendation applies to U.S. government agencies using
>   cryptography for the protection of their sensitive, unclassified
>   information.

and in Section 1.3Scope

> All cryptographic algorithms currently approved by NIST for the
>   protection of unclassified, but sensitive information are in scope.

What are the NIST Recommendations for Protection of sensitive and classified data in terms of Cryptographic primitives

1. Symmetric Encryption
2. Asymmetric Encryption
3. Hash Functions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_Suite_B_Cryptography

Comment: any link to NIST documentation stating details about suite A and Suite B

Comment: Suite A is classified; NIST will not have any documentation about it.

Comment: [NSA recommendations for information up to Top Secret](https://www.keylength.com/en/6/)

Comment: @poncho any documentation of suite B?

Comment: @poncho Suite A: clear proof that security through obscurity works and that Kerckhoff was wrong?

Comment: @PaulUszak, for the average (or even above average) person/organization Kerckhoff still applies.

Comment: @mikeazo Am I average?

Comment: @PaulUszak, I'd say the majority of our users are above average ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suite B has been revised in the light of development of quantum algorithms. Some modifications to ECC standards was in response to the scandal of an apparent weak elliptic curve in the previous standard.

From the NSA IAD website:

> Commercial National Security Algorithm Suite
>
> The Commercial National Security Algorithm Suite (CNSA Suite) will
>   provide new algorithms for those customers who are looking for
>   mitigations to perform, replacing the current Suite B algorithms.
>
> [..]
>
> Currently, Suite B cryptographic algorithms are specified by the
>   National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) and are used by
>   NSA's Information Assurance Directorate in solutions approved for
>   protecting classified and unclassified National Security Systems
>   (NSS). Below, we announce preliminary plans for transitioning to
>   quantum resistant algorithms.
>
> Background
>
> IAD will initiate a transition to quantum resistant algorithms in the
>   not too distant future. Based on experience in deploying Suite B, we
>   have determined to start planning and communicating early about the
>   upcoming transition to quantum resistant algorithms. Our ultimate goal
>   is to provide cost effective security against a potential quantum
>   computer.  We are working with partners across the USG, vendors, and
>   standards bodies to ensure there is a clear plan for getting a new
>   suite of algorithms that are developed in an open and transparent
>   manner that will form the foundation of our next Suite of
>   cryptographic algorithms.
>
> Until this new suite is developed and products are available
>   implementing the quantum resistant suite, we will rely on current
>   algorithms. For those partners and vendors that have not yet made the
>   transition to Suite B elliptic curve algorithms, we recommend not
>   making a significant expenditure to do so at this point but instead to
>   prepare for the upcoming quantum resistant algorithm transition.
>
> For those vendors and partners that have already transitioned to Suite
>   B, we recognize that this took a great deal of effort on your part,
>   and we thank you for your efforts. We look forward to your continued
>   support as we work together to improve information security for
>   National Security customers against the threat of a quantum computer
>   being developed. Unfortunately, the growth of elliptic curve use has
>   bumped up against the fact of continued progress in the research on
>   quantum computing, which has made it clear that elliptic curve
>   cryptography is not the long term solution many once hoped it would
>   be.  Thus, we have been obligated to update our strategy.
>
> It is important to note that we aren't asking vendors to stop
>   implementing the Suite B algorithms and we aren't asking our national
>   security customers to stop using these algorithms.  Rather, we want to
>   give more flexibility to vendors and our customers in the present as
>   we prepare for a quantum safe future. Where elliptic curve protocols
>   are to be used, we prefer Suite B standards be used to the fullest
>   extent possible as they have a long history of security evaluation and
>   time tested implementation that newer proposals do not yet have.

There are links to documents for implementers and users as well.

https://www.iad.gov/iad/programs/iad-initiatives/cnsa-suite.cfm